# Copying code from GitHub to GitLab - code gets copied at different location

Tags: github, gitlab

I am trying to copy one private repository from Github to GitLab. A project is created on gitlab with an empty sub group where I have role assigned to me as Maintainer. Let's say the sub group is called as `temp`. So the place where files need to copied is `https://gitlab.com/project_name/temp`.

I have cloned the github repository on my local system and used

```
git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/project_name/temp
git push -f origin master
```

while this executes but I get a warning

> warning: redirecting to https://gitlab.com/my_username/temp/

and the code is not copied here `https://gitlab.com/project_name/temp` but at `https://gitlab.com/my_username/temp/` where `my_username` is my username on gitlab.

Why does this happen and what can I do to correctly copy the repository at right location?

I have been trying many ways to do this and I am not sure if I have corrupted/changed something in the process.

Comment: Caveat: I use a private version of gitlab but I believe it works the same. gitlab expects repos to under personal groups (named after your username) or groups - a bit like github with personal or organisation areas, but with the bonus the gitlab also supports subgroups. I guess "myproject" in this context is the group. So the question: you need to have created a repo on gitlab before you can push to it, where did you create that? I would expect you to create that under the temp subgroup? That will tell you the url to push to. As it stands, you seem to be mixing up subgroups and repos.

Comment: "Group" here seems to be a GitLab-specific concept. There's nothing in generic Git like this. (GitHub has access controls, but they're not based on "groups": GitHub has "organizations" instead. These may or may not function the same way.)

Comment: Yes groups and subgroups are gitlab specific. However think of them as directories of repos - little to do with git itself.. You need, as I said, to create your repo in the correct place in the group you want it to be in: go the the appropriate group page and use the "New Project" button. The "project" is the repo - not the same as projects on github. You might be able to import from github (depends on the visibility but worth a try) or create a blank repo - in the latter case it will tell you the url to use for "git remove set-url..." and you can push your existing repo contents.